# Efficiently instantiate vector<char> from char*

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have a hot spot in my code where I need to call a library function that takes a `vector<char> vec` and I have the data as a `char* data` along with a `size_t len` length. I currently do:

```
vec.reserve(len);
std::copy(data, data+len, back_inserter(vec));
```

and like I said this is a hot spot. I wonder if copying one byte at a time is too slow and it would be faster to copy 4 or 8 bytes in each iteration. I'm also not aware that there's a way to populate a vector this way (since it requires writing to its `data()` member).

Is there a way, maybe, to avoid the copy altogether?

Comment: I would expect std::copy to be efficient, i.e. for an array of chars just a memcpy with CPU-specific ASM would probably be used internally. But avoiding copy altogether is of course even better ;)

Comment: Consider redesigning this library function's interface; only accepting vector is pretty weak

Comment: The library provides functionality similar to Google's Protocol Buffers. Data is stored according to a schema and then can be serialized. The data is stored in memory as a std::vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vec.swap( std::vector<char>(data, data + len) );
```

This creates a new temporary (anonymous) vector object with contents `data` and replaces vec with this contents.

Make sure to profile it with other alternatives before deploying. Also question yourself to make sure that you use an `std::vector` and not `std::string` or something else.

---

A hacky way would be:

```
vec.resize(len);
std::memcpy(&vec[0], data, len); // include <cstring>
```

`memcpy` would possibly copy multiple bytes at a time using native assembly instruction and should be faster.

Comment: Doesn't this involve the same linear copy?

Comment: Using other methods like `std::vector::resize` + `std::memcpy` appear hacky.

Comment: I'll do some testing to see what's the % improvement, but I just might go with hacky. Thanks.

Comment: Your `vec.swap( std::vector<char>(data, data + len) );` is generally worse than `assign`, as it throws away `vec`'s currently allocated memory, which may already have been sufficient for the data, with the temporary necessarily doing an allocation.

Comment: @TonyD Is there a guarantee that anonymous vector won't be optimized out?

Comment: @MohitJain; I don't see how it can be guaranteed that it will be - a dynamic memory allocation needs to be thread safe which by itself is probably enough to prevent optimisation, and in some implementations sits atop `malloc` which - being an `extern` function in the C library - which it's valid and useful to intercept with debug version etc. - isn't very amenable to optimisation.

Answer (score 8):

You can just do

```
vec.assign(data, data + len);
```

Or if it's a new variable, use the appropriate constructor:

```
std::vector<char> vec(data, data + len);
```

It should be a bit more efficient than `push_back()` one by one (profile it though), but anyway it's a copy.

You can't avoid the copy unless you either use `vector<char>` for your data from the start, or change the library code.

At least, you can reuse `vec` between calls to the library (by calling `assign`), so you save some time on memory allocations.